# Hibernate repo query to access mongodb embedded document

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a mongo document like this:

```
{  
   "user":{  
      "name":"String",
      "Department":{  
         "departName":"String",
         "departId":0
      }
   }
}
```

So I have a nested json Departament, my spring-hibernate entity is this:

```
@Document(collection:"user") 
class User(){
    String name
    Department department    
}
```

and the class Department:

```
class Department(){
    String departName
    Integer departId  
}
```

I wanna query by departName, this is easily done in mongo query language like this:

```
db.user.find("user.department.departName":"HHRR")
```

So, what I need to do is the same query in spring data code. I have a mongoRepository and this is what I jave tried so far:

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {

public Customer findByDepartment(Department department);
}
```

But this is not working because it is making a query by both, departmentName and departmentId and I only have the department Name.

I want to do something similar to this:

```
public Customer findByDepartment.departName(String DepartName);
```

Can I achieve this using spring-hibernate code?

if this is not possible, can I use the mongo query somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Hibernate.
Yes you can achieve this by

```
public Customer findByDepartment_DepartName(String DepartName);
```

Spring data will formulate the query based on method name

Comment: It worked like a charm, this is exactly I was trying to do... such a bad documentation...
thank you very much!